# prime interval(PRINT) on SPOJ

Tags: primes

I implemented a sieve for finding prime numbers between given range by first finding primes  up to square root of highest possible number for upperlimit of interval and then for each test case find prime numbers up to required limit.I start marking composite from square of each prime.
This gets AC in SPOJ PRIME1( http://www.spoj.com/problems/PRIME1/ ) in 0.07 but gets TLE for PRIME INTERVAL-PRINT. (http://www.spoj.com/problems/PRINT/) How can I improve this?

Comment: the reason for TLE is your use of `long long int`. `int` will get your through, but then you need to be careful about the corner cases, they *will* throw them at you.

Comment: Thank you, it worked. Can you please tell me why does code with long long int takes more time and how much extra time does it take?

Comment: compare `printf("%d %d", (int)sizeof(long long int), (int)sizeof(char))`. it ought to be 8 vs 1 or something. so it takes 8 times more memory than necessary, so it doesn't fit to cache as well and so works much slower. how much slower, you can measure on ideone.com. would appreciate if you'd post your results back here. :)

Comment: I tried ideone but it showed 0s for both so I tried on my laptop using clock() but it included time required to print numbers too.  I used input :10 2146483647 2147483647....(same limits 10 times) and the difference between two codes was approx 11s(code with int was faster).  but when I used same input one time code with long long int was approx  0.5 s faster.  PS: My laptop has Intel core i5 4th gen with 2gb ram

Comment: maybe SPOJ has old slow 32-bit computers. who knows.

Comment: They use "intel Pentium G860 3GHz"